# What is $I(X_i < \overline{X})$?

Tags: terminology

I have a problem that involves the term $I(X_i < \overline{X})$. The only reference to this in the question is "trimmed means", but I believe it references the entire function $\frac{\sum X_i I(X_i < \overline{X})}{\sum I(X_i < \overline{X})}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$I()$ is the 'indicator' function. It is equal to 1 if the condition inside of the parentheses is true and 0 otherwise.

So, take a look at the second equation you gave. The numerator will be the sum only of the values that are smaller than $\bar{X}$ and the denominator will be the number of value that are smaller than $\bar{X}$. So, this is just a way of writing the mean of the value when trimming away first all values that are larger than $\bar{X}$.

Comment: `(x < y)` would be interpreted in many languages as a true or false statement with numeric result, often but not always 1 if true and 0 if false. APL from the 1960s on was an influential example. Similar notation has often been urged as good mathematical practice. See Donald Knuth's work e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9205211 and many of his books. In short the `I()` is packaging that many are happy to discard.